# Как сделать 3-х уровневую реф-систему на PHP Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Приветствую, подскажите как построить логику 3-х уровневой реферальной системы на PHP и Mysql, например если был переход по реф ссылке в куки записывается пользователь и при регистрации присваивается ref_id и ref_name.

```
$re = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$ref_id'") or 
die(mysql_error());
$re1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($re);
$ref_name = clean(sf($re1['login']));
$ref_id = clean(sf($re1['id']));

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET kol_ref = kol_ref + 1 WHERE id = '$ref_id'"); // Добавляем +1 реферала

/* Процесс регистрации */ 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (name, login, pass, date_reg, ip, ref_id, 
ref_name, mail) VALUES ('$names', '$login', '$passmd5', '$date', '$ip', 
'$ref_id', '$ref_name','$mail')")or die(mysql_error());
```

так вот как добавлять рефералов 2 и 3 уровня? Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Какая у вас версия php? Мне просто интересно.

Comment: Версия php 5.3.

Comment: Сохраняйте уровень реферала отдельной колонкой, default 0. Пишете туда `$re1['ref_level']+1`

Comment: В вашем коде большой простор для sql-инъекций и давно устаревший API доступа к mysql.

Comment: Спасибо за совет.